# Why the app produced by flutter build web sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 issues that only appear when executing `flutter build web`.

1. Sometimes `flutter build web` fails complaining (wrongly) about types that were not compatible (see below).
2. Sometimes the build process finishes but then the web app doesn't work: doesn't display anything and there are no messages in the console.

The error I mention is something like this:

```
% flutter build web
Target dart2js failed: Exception: lib/main.dart:24:31:                  
Error: A value of type 'ApiUsersRepository' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'UsersRepository'.
 - 'ApiUsersRepository' is from 'package:my_app/api_users_repo.dart' ('lib/api_users_repo.dart').
 - 'UsersRepository' is from 'lib/users_repo.dart'.
  final UsersRepository usersRepository = ApiUsersRepository();
                              ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

The app is working in iOS and web when developing.

Answer (score 3):

**The solution**

I changed all imports of my files like:

```
import 'package:my_app/users_repo.dart';
```

To:

```
import 'users_repo.dart';
```

**More Details**

Investigating the error about types, I found this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47692), where the important part is this comment: **after changing every import to relative format it resolves my problem**.

So I did that, and it solved the 2 issues, the compilation error, and the runtime error.

Comment: What is the reason this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think that the dart2js compiler thinks that those packages are different. Must be a bug there.

Answer (score 0):

for me I had to remove a package that was corrupted.  c:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\localstorage-4.0.0+1    Apparently, a file had become corrupted by me invertly.   I removed the package and did a flutter pub get then recompiled and it worked.